# Building a specific version of Perl in a specific place

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu

I would like to build a version of Perl that is separate from the system version.

1. Initially in my own directory ~/perl/perl-5.12.3
2. Eventaully I want to install it in /usr/local/perl-5.12.3

I realise that `perlbrew` will help with the 1. but not (as I understand it) 2.  So I think I would be better building it by hand.

What option do I need to give go `Configure.sh` to get it to install in a particular directory - and not try and install into my own directory (and not try to install man pages into  /usr/local/man/man1)

**Update**
Followed instruction below. This corrects the `bin = /usr/local/bin` but I am still getting following. Do I need to configure this separately

```
scriptdir = /usr/local/bin
shrpdir = /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i686-linux/CORE
man1dir = /usr/local/man/man1
man3dir = /usr/local/man/man3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configure.sh -Dinstallprefix=/whereever/you/want/it/installed

Comment: thanks @ennuikiller - moving in the right direction but see addition to my question.

Comment: Then just use `-Dprefix=...`. This will put the `bin`, `lib`, and `man` files under a common arbitrary directory.

Comment: OK - that worked.  I had actually tried it, but I think it was getting old values from `config.sh`

Comment: Are the options to Configure documented anywhere?  And the interaction with config.sh

Comment: In the [INSTALL](http://p3rl.org/Install) file. Next time, better [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) when the topic has drifted.